# What is the difference between defer object promise and promise from $resource service

Tags: angularjs, promise

What is the difference between defer object promise and promise from `$resource` service?

I know, that in some cases one uses `$q` service to create `deferer`, then resolve response and return promise.

Others in the same time might do something like `return $resource(...).get().$promise;`.

What is the diff. between those two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise returned from `$resource` is one someone initially used `$q.defer()` (or the newer more modern promise constructor) to create.

That someone is the `$http` service used internally inside `$resource` - you are using a promise they created for you.

Typically, you only need to use a `$q.defer` or the promise constructor at the lowest level of your code when working with async - otherwise you're typically better off using promise chaining. Otherwise you end up [with the explicit construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: So to simply put it http and q service, or more advanced resource service with chained promise call, right? As I understand your answer the http and q are just leftovers, that some developers still use?

Comment: @Eugene no, they're lower level primitives. `$resource` for rest management is built over `$http` for HTTP calls which is built over `$q` for promises and `XMLHTTPRequest` for web calls. Certainly not leftovers - there are lots of use cases for $http without $resource (for calls to non-rest services or a different style of calls for rest services) and a lot of use cases for $q without $http (for non http APIs - for example $timeout returns a promise).

Comment: Okay. So just different usage scopes.